# PHP Website - Navigation links with sub directories

Tags: php

I have a site with this directory structure:

```
index.php
folder1/index.php
folder2/index.php
inc/nav.php
```

All the index.php pages include the nav.php page which contains the top horizontal navigation bar, e.g.:

```
<?php include_once 'inc/nav.php' ?>
```

Inside the nav.php file are the links to various pages, eg. home and logout etc. These work fine when on the index.php file at the site root, but when on any of the index.php pages in any of the subfolders these don't work as they link to:

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/folder1/logout.php
```

whereas the link should be to:

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/logout.php
```

The nav.php has links like this:

```
<li> <a href="logout.php">Logout</a> </li>
```

so I see how that only works when called from the root index.php page but can't work out how to have it so that it works from any index.php page whether at the site root level or a subfolder.

Comment: Change <a href="logout.php"> to <a href="/logout.php">

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you've logout.php on the root, use a slash before the page name like this, to point the page from the root.

```
<li> <a href="/logout.php">Logout</a> </li>
```

As what you are using is just `logout.php` which will point the page name in that specific directory, but the server will return 404 as it may be available when you are on the root, but it will fail when you are in the directory.

If it still complicates the navigation, you can also use `if` conditions to change the paths accordingly.

Comment: Thanks - I ended up having to use a series of if and } elseif ( to get the desired result